# How do I drop observations based on their observation (row) number within a by group?

Tags: sas

In Stata, I can do this:

```
bysort group_var: drop if _n > 6
```

to keep only the first six observations *within each group* as specified by `group_var`. How do I do this in SAS?

I tried:

```
proc sort data=indata out=sorted_data;
    by group_var;
run;

data outdata;
    set sorted_data;
    by group_var;
    if (_n_ > 6) then delete;
run;
```

but this deletes all but the first six observations in the entire dataset (leaving me with only six observations total).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to count records in each by group.

```
data outdata;
   set sorted_data;
   by group_var;
   retain count;

   if first.group_var then
      count = 0;

   count = count + 1;
   if count > 6 then delete;

   drop count;
run;
```

Comment: And of course could save a line by using `count+1;`.

Comment: @Joe, agree 100%.  This is a little more self-explanatory for a new SAS coder.  I, personally, tend to do it this way, knowing that others will have to read my code, and not everyone will be well versed in SAS.

Comment: Hmm.  I tend to consider `count+1;` as sufficiently basic that anyone should understand it, but I suppose that may not always be true.

Comment: @Joe As someone new to SAS (but not new to programming), I find `count+1;` quite ambiguous, because in other languages, I would expect a statement like that to have no effect because its result isn't assigned to anything, and it's not necessarily idiomatic across languages like increment/decrement operators.

Comment: Oh, in an answer like this I'd certainly explain it (as I have a few dozen times).  That was more addressing Dom's comment about not using it in his own (work) code.

Comment: I would add as a separate note that I like using it (`count+1;`) specifically because it is a very clear way of denoting a counter increment (and I wouldn't use `count` of course!).  Scanning a program, I can easily identify counters this way whereas the `count=count+1;` is less clear (as there are many other reasons you would want to increment a variable by one).